# Facebook Photo Size in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimageview

Right now with the Facebook iOS sdk, I am pulling images off the wall. but I need to analyze the photo and determine the height and width of the photo.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You might want to change the correct answer as the other answer doesn't really answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is an old question which has been answered, but since the accepted answer is very unclear and because this might help others that have the same problem as you had:

Given that the images that you pull off the wall are turned into UIImage objects before you display them, then you can just do the following to easily get the height and width of each object:

Full code example:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourimageurlhere]];
UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
[imageData release];

NSLog(@"Height : %0.1f", image.size.height);
NSLog(@"Width : %0.1f", image.size.width);
```

Answer (score -1):

when you issue a call to [GraphAPI photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object, you get dimensions in the response: https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305

is it what are you looking for?

Comment: Kind of, I was looking for when I call me/feed and I get a response with a photo in it. When I call me/feed there are no dimensions that came with that.

Comment: i think in this case you are out of luck.

Comment: is there no classes that someone has that determine the dimensions of an uiimage??

Comment: hold on. If you want FB to return you dimensions of the image - that's one thing. If you want to download image from FB directly to your iOS application and then determine image size - that's another thing. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531409/ios-how-to-get-image-dimensions-without-opening-it